# How to create a nullable store in svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

How can I create a store that is nullable?
Use case: At the beginning its null, then it gets set.

This does not work:

```js
export const provider = readable(null, (set) => {
    const unwatch = watchProvider({}, (provider) => {
        set(provider); // sets it to type Provider
    });

    return () => {
        unwatch();
    };
});
```

Comment: *How* does this not work?